pip install quickfix failed in windows
I'm trying to install the quikcfix library on my windows machine. The python version is 3.12.2.
However I get the below error.
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully
exit code: 1
[7 lines of output]
Testing for std::tr1::shared_ptr...
...not found
Testing for std::shared_ptr...
...not found
Testing for std::unique_ptr...
...not found
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I installed the Microsoft C++ build tools as well. But it still gives the same error.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this error

Which version of the C++ compiler do you have installed?

Download the quickfix from here:
https://github.com/kazcfz/QuickFIX-prebuilt-wheel
What I see from the link,
the latest version of python which supports quickfix is 3.9
It will not work for python 3.12


Those are prebuilt wheels. The error output seems like it's being built from source

Hmm.. you are right! python 3.12 is never supported though.

This solved my issue

Note the error text "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required." So try to install c++ 14.x. When you install the required components you should not get the error.
The link in the error text and this will help you:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

This is more of a comment. It was mentioned in the question that it was installed

sorry I didn't realize this but maybe a clean boot might help, uninstalling components and reinstalling the most compatible versions might solve the problem.
